# How to Test a Database connection with spid?

Tags: java, sql-server, database

If we have a username, password and JDBC connection URL. I test the DB connection using:-

```
DriverManager.getConnection(connectionurl,username,password);
```

But, In my case i have only the JDBC URL and pksd. How to test a db with the url and spid in java?

Here pksd is a kind of certificate for authentication.

Comment: SPID = Server Process ID, this term is used by Microsoft, so I would say that the database is a MSSQL server.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you see as 'testing a database'. Do you want to check if the server responds to incoming connections? Then you can test that using only the JDBC URL. Simply open the connection (maybe with a random username/password combination) and see if the server responds with an 'Access denied' error or something. If you get a timeout or some other connection error, something went wrong.

If you want to execute a specific query and the result of that query is important for your test (so the query has to be executed properly), the only way you can test that is when you know a username/password so you can log in to the SQL server and do your thing. Another option would be to enable anonymous access to your database (possibly with very limited privileges), but you should think twice about it before doing this.

Also, doing a fallback is also possible:

```
DriverManager.getConnection(connectionurl);
```